# domain.com?p=POSTID permalinks not working with custom post types

Tags: permalinks

I use the default Wordpress permalinks as shortlinks on my site, and just noticed that they are not working for custom post type links. Instead they give a 404 error.

These work for for the 'post' post type, but not for anything else.

Is this normal?

Here is the custom post type declaration:

```
function register_fact_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Facts', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Fact', 'post type singular name'),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Facts', 'admin menu'),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Fact', 'add new on admin bar'),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Fact'),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Fact'),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Fact'),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Fact'),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Fact'),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Facts'),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Facts'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Facts:'),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Facts found.'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Facts found in Trash.')
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'facts' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
        );

    register_post_type( 'fact', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_fact_post_type', 1);
```

Comment: It depends on how you registered your custom post type - could you share the arguments you are using?

Comment: Does flushing rewrite rules correct the issue? Do you get redirected to the pretty permalink URL?

Comment: @bosco - I added the custom post type declaration code :)

Comment: @TomJNowell - No I tried that :/